# SQL Developer queries are very slow if I am not connected as sys

Tags: user-permissions, query, slow-connection, plsql, sqldeveloper

I want to run my PL/SQL Queries on SQL Developer and created a new user connection. But if I run:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited;

begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello Oracle.');
end;
/

clear screen;
```

It takes more then 100 seconds.
But only if I am connected to a user wit default role. It is very fast when I am connected to sys.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I miss quite some information in this question, f.ex:

- Version of SQL Developer.
- Version of database.
- State of database (just created, cloned, whatever).

However, it does sound like one of 2 possible things:

1. Missing stats (Fixed stats and system stats).
2. A bug in grants hierarchy, which could indicate the database to be 12.2 or 18C? - in this case I believe a patch exists.